# versioning / logging changes to a db model

Tags: database, algorithm

Suppose you have two models: `Book`s and `Collection`s. A `Collection` has one or more `Book`s. Now you have an API where you can go to `/collections/1` to get all the books in collection 1, for example.

But collections will change over time! Books will be added or removed. So now I want a new resource, `collection_changes/:id`. I give it a timestamp and it returns a list of all the books that have been added or removed from the collection since then.

Is there a fast, efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @KevinVaughan Since the timestamp he mentioned.

Comment: Durr, slow brain afternoon. Clarification question deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep a sorted (by timestamp) list of changes to each collection (changes will be added at the end and never removed, so this is efficient). Then you can find a given timestamp in logarithmic time by binary search, and just return the portion of the list following the timestamp.